# How to make user able to introduce block quotes like stack overflow?

Tags: html, markdown

How can I make a user introduce blockquotes or bold text by himself like stack overflow ? and how does stack overflow change blockquotes to '>' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) to HTML converter. Probably the best for you would be a  Javascript converter. Look at this link for the [Showdown Converter](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown).

Comment: thanks man,thanks alot.